# Storing column for data that doesn't exist for majority of rows

Tags: mysql, database-design, mariadb, design-pattern

I'm using mariadb.

I have a single table that keeps track of `video_count` and `image_count` for a few different sites. I.e.

```
 type        | enum('SITE1','SITE2','SITE3')                                
 video_count | int(11)                                                
 image_count | int(11)
```

`video_count` will exist for ALL sites but `image_count` only exists for `SITE3`. Also, SITE3 will be a minority of rows.

So does it make sense to arrange the data this way on one table?
I'd like to query ALL rows...but is it a problem if it's redundant and expensive knowing that 90% of my rows will have `0` for image_count?

It'd be perfect if I could do something like `SELECT * from TABLE BUT DON't GET video_count WHERE type != 'SITE3'"`

Is that even a possible query in SQL? Or does it now make sense to create separate tables for 'SITE1...SITEN'? Ty!

Comment: You seem to be engaging in premature optimisation. The overhead of maintaining and having to query multiple tables will be worse.

Comment: Yeah, I'd like to avoid multiple tables. So seems like it's not much to worry about? But say for example I'm getting a ton of unnecessary `image_counts`..will this lead to scalability issue...(seeing as it's redundant knowing they'll always be 0)

Comment: They don't usually measure data volume and transaction performance in tons, so I don't know how much that is. However, speaking about scalability, at the scale this "issue" starts to move the performance needle, you'll be worried about other, more important things.

Comment: Was thinking like >10k+ rows. What are more important things I'd worry about?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Very_large_database

Comment: Is `type` the `PRIMARY KEY`??

Comment: No, `pk` is just an auto_increment id int

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend storing NULL in the `image_count` column on rows where it is inapplicable because the type doesn't need it. NULL is different from an integer 0.

InnoDB doesn't store a value in the row for a NULL. So it's pretty low overhead to leave the column NULL on the rows that don't need it. There's a bit stored in the row header for each nullable column, but that will be needed whether you store a value or not.

10k rows is small for an InnoDB table. I wouldn't worry about it unless you need to run this database on a Raspberry Pi or similarly compact platform.

SQL does not have any syntax for `SELECT * except-the-columns-I-don't-want`. If you use `SELECT *`, that means all the columns, including those that are NULL. If you want a subset of columns, you have to name all of the ones you want.

Comment: I MODIFIED the COLUMN to DEFAULT to NULL, ty

Comment: Count of 0 is not the same as NULL (as you yourself say), so you can't substitute one for the other. The count of 0 reflects the fact that no images exist; the NULL  count indicates that we don't know if images exist or not.

Comment: @mustaccio, Yep, that's correct. NULL is also used when the datum is inapplicable. I understood the OP's situation to be that the image count is not relevant to `SITE3`.